# Core Data in Swift

Tags: core-data, nsarray, swift, nsmanagedobjectcontext, ios8

Trying to work with Core Data in Swift. Found this one example:

http://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2014/06/23/a-c-developer-learns-swift-part-1-core-data/

Created Entity "**Person**" with two string fields - **lastname** and **firstname**. Created UITableViewController (**MainTableViewController**) to display records on the screen. Created UIViewController (**DetailViewController**) to add new records. Created my own class (AddrBook) for entity data.

***Does not work display the records contained in the entity in main class - MainTableViewController.***

My class **AddrBook.swift**:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(AddrBook)
class AddrBook: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var lastname:String
@NSManaged var firstname:String
}
```

UIViewController to add new records. **DetailViewController.swift**:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var lastNameField : UITextField = nil
@IBOutlet var firstNameField : UITextField = nil

init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {

    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let projectEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    var newPerson = AddrBook(entity: projectEntity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newPerson.lastname = lastNameField.text
    newPerson.firstname = firstNameField.text
    context.save(nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Theoretically, in this class all goes well. Entry must be added.

The main class **MainTableViewController.swift**. To display the records. Trying to get them through the NSLog:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {

init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
    for currentPerson in results as AddrBook[] {
        NSLog("\(currentPerson.lastname)")
        NSLog("\(currentPerson.firstname)")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}
}
```

Shows that there is an error in the expression

```
for currentPerson in results as AddrBook[] {
```

Error:

**Cannot convert the expression's type 'AddrBook[]' to type 'AddrBook[]'**

What am I doing wrong?

---

for LombaX:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    var results : AddrBook[]? = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as? AddrBook[]
    NSLog("\(results)")
    if let array = results   // check for nil and unwrap
    {
        for currentPerson in array as AddrBook[] {
            NSLog("\(currentPerson.lastname)")
            NSLog("\(currentPerson.firstname)")
        }
    }

    // var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
    /*for currentPerson in results as AddrBook[] {
        NSLog("\(currentPerson.lastname)")
        NSLog("\(currentPerson.firstname)")
    }*/

}
```

Output NSLog - **2014-06-24 21:25:41.243 lesson-12-swift[1651:136375] nil**

Variable **results** is nil :-(

**Link to project in Dropbox:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/q42rw5fw470timi/lesson-12-swift.zip

Comment: First: remove the for and put a breakpoint after results = ... . Look in the variables window: is your array correctly filled with AddrBook objects? Moreover, Did you put, in your model file, the class name as "ProjectName.AddrBook"?

Comment: Tried. Result screenshot: [link](http://prntscr.com/3w25zf)  results=(_PFArray *)@"1 object"  [0] (<invalid>)

Comment: Variable window is a little bit bugged now...what if you println(results) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check that you filled the class in the data model:
As `ProjectName.AddrBook` (for swift classes you have to specify even the project name). (NOTE: this is needed only if you haven't used the prefix @objc(AddrBook) before the class, but I see that you used it, so this is not the problem).

or

as AddrBook as in this image in the Class section, top right

[image: Data Model]

Moreover, change your cast like these:

```
// since executeFetchRequest can return nil, cast it as an optional array of [AddrBook]
// note: the first [AddrBook]? Can be omitted
var results : [AddrBook]? = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as? [AddrBook]  

if let array = results   // check for nil and unwrap
{
    for currentPerson in array as [AddrBook] {
        // print
    }
}
```

Or, less explicit and no check for nil

```
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)  

    for currentPerson in results as [AddrBook] {
        // print
    }
```

Comment: Please add the details to the original question, not as a new answer. However, if results is nil, you should check for the error. Pass an NSError variable as &error and check the returned error

Comment: Сould you see my project and help to understand? Please... Link to Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q42rw5fw470timi/lesson-12-swift.zip

Comment: Look at the image added, that was your problem. I checked fast, if it doesn't work I'll check again once I came back to the pc (1-2 hours)

Comment: Yes! It's work! I did this: http://prntscr.com/3w2seg   And this is result: http://prntscr.com/3w2tph   Now I will try continue to work with Core Data. Thank you! Can I ask a couple of questions later? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
   let arrayresult = context!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

    var arrayvalues=NSArray(array: arrayresult!)


    for obj in arrayvalues as [AddrBook]
    {

    }
```